# Switch to new page when I use ctrl+click in Firefox

Tags: firefox, shortcuts, hyperlink

When I use Ctrl+Click on a link in Firefox to open it in a new tab, I would like to automatically switch to that new tab. Is there any way this can be achieved? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In *Firefox Settings*, search on *new tab*.

[image: Open new tab]

Check the box for *When you open... switch to it immediately*.

BTW, middle-mouse button click can be set to open a new tab, too, avoiding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key press... a worksaver ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Go to `about:preferences` in the address bar, and check the box next to **When you open a link, image or media in a new tab, switch to it immediately** (Under the **Tabs** section). This setting will also apply to middle-clicking a link, or just using the "Open Link in New Tab" option of the context menu.